# I can't delete a video file in java. File open with java binary process

Tags: java, html, file, video

I am trying to delete a video file using this code:

```
File f = new File(filePath)                                                         
boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  f.delete()
```

Before I open a html page that call the video with the html tag:

CONTROLLER:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${fileName}")
response.getOutputStream() << file.newInputStream()
```

HTML/VIEW:

```
<video class="img-responsive" controls="">
<source src="/documento/download?id=1" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Everything works except that when I try to delete the boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted returns false and when I go to the folder to delete the file returns that I can't delete the video file because is open with java binary process, even if I change the webpage to another that dont have the video file.

Thanks in advance
Serge Nunes.